# Date-select onChange equivalent/fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby-generated `date_select` which, when changed by the user (eg change the month), should fire a javascript function `resetBusyList()`. But this does not happen.

When using this same technique on other HTML elements it works fine, but I know that there is some problem with date_select and onChange. I have tried to research and look at the API, but I don't understand what I am supposed to do. Here is my code:

## html.erb

```
<%= f.date_select :day, { id: "date-select", onChange: "resetBusyList()"} %>

<ol id="unavailable-list">
              <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

## application.js

```
function resetBusyList(){
    document.getElementById("unavailable-list").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Sorry if this is really obvious to you, but I am very new to programming! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/date_select):

`date_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

So you should change your code to:

`<%= f.date_select :day, {}, { id: "date-select", onChange: "resetBusyList()"} %>`

Comment: when I change it to that I get an argument error: wrong number of arguments (4 for 1..3)